# How do you split a string at a specific point?

Tags: python, split, text-files

I am new to python and want to split what I have read in from a text file into two specific parts. Below is an example of what could be read in:

```
f = ['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]
```

So what I want to achieve is to be able to execute the second part of the program is:

```
words = ['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.']

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]
```

I have tried using:

```
words,numbers = f.split("][")
```

However, this removes the double bracets from the two new variable which means the second part of my program which recreates the original text does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `f` is a string like

```
f = "['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]"
```

then we can find the index of `][` and add one to find the point between the brackets

```
i = f.index('][')
a, b = f[:i+1], f[i+1:]
print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.']
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Alternative if you want to still use `split()`

```
f = "['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]"
d="]["
print f.split(d)[0]+d[0]
print d[1]+f.split(d)[1]
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `split` twice; it would be better to save its result in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make your file look something like this:

```
[["Cats","like","dogs","as","much","cats."],[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]]
```

then you could simply use Python's json module to do this for you.  Note that the JSON format requires double quotes rather than single.

```
import json
f = '[["Cats","like","dogs","as","much","cats."],[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]]'
a, b = json.loads(f)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Documentation for the json library can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Patrick's answer using regular expressions:

```
import re

data = "f = ['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]"
pattern = 'f = (?P<words>\[.*?\])(?P<numbers>\[.*?\])'

match = re.match(pattern, data)
words = match.group('words')
numbers = match.group('numbers')

print(words)
print(numbers)
```

**Output**

```
['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.']
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a text file that contains `['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]` and you just need to split that string at the transition between brackets. You can do this with the `string.index()` method and string slicing. See my console output below:

```
>>> f = open('./catsdogs12.txt', 'r')
>>> input = f.read()[:-1]  # Read file without trailing newline (\n)
>>> input
"['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]"
>>> bracket_index = input.index('][')  # Get index of transition between brackets
>>> bracket_index
41
>>> words = input[:bracket_index + 1]  # Slice from beginning of string
>>> words
"['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.']"
>>> numbers = input[bracket_index + 1:]  # Slice from middle of string
>>> numbers
'[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]'
```

Note that this will leave you with a python string that looks visually identical to a list (array). If you needed the data represented as python native objects (i.e. so that you can actually use it like a list), you'll need to use some combination of `string[1:-1].split(',')` on both strings and `list.map()` on the numbers list to convert the numbers from strings to numbers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, very useful and well annotated for beginners to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is first replace `][`  with `]-[` and then do a split or partition using `-` but i will suggest you to do split as we don't want that delimiter.

**SPLIT**

```
f = "['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]" 
f = f.replace('][',']-[')
a,b = f.split('-')
```

Output

```
>>> print(a)
['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.']
>>> print(b)
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]
```

**PARTITION**

```
f = "['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.'][1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]"
f = f.replace('][',']-[')
a,b,c = f.partition('-')
```

Output

```
>>> print(a)
['Cats','like','dogs','as','much','cats.']
>>> print(c)
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,6]
```